# Auto submitting after login in Spring web application

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm creating Spring MVC web application for online flight reservation. This is a beginner project and my question may be too long. I've removed unneccessory codes. Here I created a jsp page which includes flight information.

`flightInfos.jsp` page

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Flight No</th>
            <th>Flight destination</th>
            <th>Flight origin</th>
            <th>Book now</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <form:form action='/flight-demo/flight-reservation.html'>
            <c:forEach items="${flightInfos}" var="flightInfo">
                <tr>
                    <td>${flightInfo.flightNo}</td> 
                    <td>${flightInfo.destination}</td>
                    <td>${flightInfo.origin}</td>
                    <td><input type="submit" value="Book now"></td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </form:form>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Once I clicked on Book now button it will check whether the user is logged in or not using Spring security. Here is my code.

`security.xml`

```
    <http use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/users**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/users/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/account**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/flight-reservation**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />

        <form-login login-page="/login.html"/>
        <csrf disabled="true"/>
        <logout logout-url="/logout" /> 
    </http>

    <!--Authentication manager-->

</beans:beans>
```

Then after user logged in to the system it will redirect user to `flight-reservation.jsp` page.

`flight-reservation.jsp`

```
<form:form modelAttribute="reservation"> 

  <c:if test="${param.ok eq true}">
    <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Registration successful.</div>
  </c:if>

    <label for="customerName"> Name </label>
    <form:input path="customerName"/>

    <label for="flightInfo"> Flight No </label>
    <form:input path="flightInfo" />

    <input type="submit" value="Save" />

</form:form>
```

Here is my `flight-reservation controller` that controls the reservations.

```
@Controller
public class FlightResController {

    @Autowired
    private FlightReservationService reservationService;

    @ModelAttribute("reservation")
    public FlightReservation construct(){
        return new FlightReservation();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/flight-reservation", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String doReservation(@ModelAttribute("reservation") FlightReservation reservation){
        reservationService.save(reservation);
        return "redirect://flight-reservation.html?ok=true";
    }   
}
```

My question is, when I click on Book now button, it checks the user is logged or not; if logged, `flight-reservation` page should be displayed. But what happen is, when I click Book now button, it display and also automatically **insert empty values** into the flight-reservation table in my database. How I can avoid this ? I'm just beginner who want to go through with `Spring MVC`. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to configure your web.xml. 
Is there the spring security filter chain defined? 
http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/security-filter-chain.html

Comment: Yes I've defined it. Both filter and mapping.

Comment: why are you using the modelAttribute? @ModelAttribute("reservation") it is always executed before each request.

Comment: I've done the same thing for user registration. It works well. Without using `@modelAttribute` how can I save that reservation ? I can't understand this. @Simone